# How to make context variable and fix error that 'Undefined name 'context'.'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a provider pattern to separate UI codes and business logic codes. It works great, but the codes are getting longer because of keep writing 'context.read<>' and 'context.watch<>' to use provider codes.
Therefore, I want to make a variable to avoid writing 'context.read<>' and 'context.watch<>'.
For example

```
isSignup = context.watch<LoginSignupData>().isSignup
```

However, it makes an error that 'Undefined name 'context'.'
Why this error happens and how can I fix this problem? Thank you!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../../Store/loginSignupData.dart';
import '../../main.dart';

class LoginSignupSendingButton extends StatelessWidget {
  LoginSignupSendingButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  var isSignup = context.read<LoginSignupData>().isSignup; //error
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedPositioned(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      curve: Curves.easeIn,
      top: context.watch<LoginSignupData>().isSignup ? 520 : 470,
      right: 0,
      left: 0,
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
          height: 90,
          width: 90,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print('isSignup : ${context.read<LoginSignupData>().isSignup}');
              context.read<LoginSignupData>().isSignup ?
                context.read<LoginSignupData>().signUp(context) : context.read<LoginSignupData>().signIn(context);
              final isValid = context.read<LoginSignupData>().formKey.currentState!.validate();
              if (context.read<LoginSignupData>().isSignupValid && isValid) {
                context.read<LoginSignupData>().formKey.currentState!.save();
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const MyApp()));
              }
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: const LinearGradient(
                    colors: [Colors.orange, Colors.red],
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                    spreadRadius: 1,
                    blurRadius: 1,
                    offset: const Offset(0, 1),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: const Icon(
                Icons.arrow_forward,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code, declare `isSignip` inside `build` method hope its help.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var isSignup = context.read<LoginSignupData>().isSignup; 
  return ...;
}
```